# Azure App Service - cannot store logs in azure storage

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, splunk

I would like to configure my diagnostic logs to be redirected to Blob or Table Storage. However the only option I see is Filesystem:
[image: App Service logs]

My goal is to collect these logs in splunk

Answer (score 2):

Currently only .NET application logs can be written to the blob storage. Java, PHP, Node.js, Python application logs can only be stored on the file system (without code modifications to write logs to external storage). I'd recommend checking the documentation [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)

Comment: It is a .net Core app. It is not clear to me whether it should work or not.

Comment: So only Web Server logging is actually supported to be stored in blob storage after doing some research, but not Application logging, the only option is File System.

Comment: Thanks! So to recap: the only solution for my problem (sending logs to Splunk) is to create custom logger that actually does not write to a file but instead to azure storage? Any recommendations? NLog plus some azure plugin maybe?

Comment: Thanks, you are correct Marcin, most users use custom solutions,i don't have any specific third party tools suggestions but most would be probably out there in the web. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs), redirecting to blob storage is only supported for Windows app service plans. Your one appears to be Linux.